# Read-Scale Availability Group between a Transactional subscriber and another machine

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to configure Read-Scale replica between a transactional subscriber and a 3rd machine. I could create the group. But, when i attempted to add the DB (which is a transactional - subscriber) to be part of my read scale replica group, I am getting the following message and not able to complete my read scale replica. My replication is already configured and working fine. Configured the AG as well. All i am doing is, trying to add the DB to the AG.

Here is the message:
Special considerations exist when adding a replication Subscriber database to an availability group. For more information, see "Replication and Availability Groups" in SQL Server Books Online.

But the BOL is not saying anything about AG on a subscriber. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you adding the subscriber database to the AG to provide scale out of read workload? If so, it might be simpler to just add the 3rd machine as another replication subscriber and get another readable copy of the replicated database that way, rather than the complexity of an AG on the subscriber DB.

Comment: have you read this?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-replication-for-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @HandyD - Well, we tried this option but the latency is too high due to geo locations. We are trying to over come this issue using AG

Comment: @MBuschi - yes. as i mentioned, we are not trying to add the publisher or distribution DBs to AG. Just adding the subscriber to AG.

Comment: @IcyHot When exactly do you encounter the error message? Can you list out the steps you're trying to take and highlight which one encounters the error?

Comment: @HandyD  When i attempt to add the DB to the AG, it throws an error as part of the verification step.

Comment: Check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/replication-subscribers-and-always-on-availability-groups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#how-to-create-transactional-subscription-in-an-always-on-environment), specifically the line `The subscription must be created by using a Transact-SQL script and cannot be created using Management Studio.`

Basically, you need to add the DB to the AG before you set it up as a subscriber DB, then configure the subscription using T-SQL and not the SSMS wizard.